# bgcolor on td does not change its color

Tags: html, css, html-email

I am using zurb foundation email html framework to display emails in email clients:

by default the button class renders a td in blue.

I set the bgcolor to red see here:

http://codepen.io/helloworld/pen/vGqPNR?editors=1100

but the color does not change!

What is the reason?

For maximum compatibility I do **NOT** want to use style="background:red"

```
<table class="button">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td bgcolor="red"><a href="#">Tiny Button</a></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You have a `table.button table td` directive in the Zurb CSS that's applied on your button. Either change that to whatever color you want, or remove the `button` class from table.

Comment: I know I have this selector. But this selector is from the source code. I just thought how I could "override" just the color. Seems I have to strip the original source css which should not be done normally!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the CSS spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#preshint):

> The UA may choose to honor presentational attributes in an HTML source document. If so, these attributes are translated to the corresponding CSS rules with specificity equal to 0, and are treated as if they were inserted at the start of the author style sheet. They may therefore be overridden by subsequent style sheet rules.

Since a CSS rule is setting a background colour on the table cell, the CSS overrides the HTML attribute.

Comment: That means that html attributes in a html tag always gets overriden by a CSS stylesheet, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's right (so long as the CSS matches the element).

Comment: Ok thanks, the premailer.net nuget will solve that problem! by rendering the css stylesheet to inline styles!

Comment: It won't, since a `style` attribute on an element will apply CSS to it and will override a `bgcolor` attribute.

Comment: Does your comment refer to the premailer nuget?

Comment: Yes, it does. Inline styles override obsolete presentational attributes just like all other styles.

Comment: Ok then everything must be done then with external stylesheet used by premailer, thanks.